# ImageView trouble

Tags: android, layout, uiimageview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView              
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/wallpaper" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The size of `@drawable/peetscoffee_wallpaper` is 640x480, but it is not centered horizontally.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `android:gravity="center"`, or `android:layout_gravity="center"`, instead of `centerHorizontal="true"`.

However, i doubt this will behave sensibly with an image that size set to `wrap_content` - you may want to define some image scaling method with `android:scaleType` (eg `fitCenter`) and set it to `fill_parent` rather than `wrap_content`. `640x480` is bigger than the `320x480` the current real-world Android devices support. Or just scale down that image you're using so the device doesn't have to do the work.